# AngularJS - Duration (time) input

Tags: angularjs, date, datetime

I am trying to create form for tracking my running and want to enter the time in `hh:mm:ss` (no AM/PM) and store it in a format I can do calculations with.

So this leaves me with 2 questions:

1. How can I set `input[time]` to `hh:mm:ss` without the AM/PM?
2. Is the best format to use `date` object type? Is it possible to store this as just `hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with standard input type=time. You will need to create your own custom input control

Comment: to manipulate time you can use moment.js. It is best to manipulate javascript Date object. This is the answer of your first question. You can store time in Date object. And whenever you require you can convert it in hh::mm:ss format. Moment.js will give you easy ways to format you date object.